# require_once(Net/URL2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory with Microsoft Face API

Tags: php, httprequest, face-detection, face-api

I have implemented microsoft face api, with the help of the library:

https://github.com/pear/HTTP_Request2

The script is working perfectly on my local machine and I can identify the faces and store them on microsoft db. But when I upload it to my server, it is showing the below error and api call won't process:

> _>require_once(Net/URL2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I have then installed the corresponding files with composer and place the folder with the 'Net' having URL.php..but then it shows the following error.

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught <table style="border: 1px"
>   cellspacing="0"> <tr><td colspan="3"
>   style="background: #ff9999">
>   <b>HTTP_Request2_ConnectionException</b>: Unable to
>   connect to tls://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com:443. Error:
>   stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   tls://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com:443 (Unknown error)
>   stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
>   stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
>   Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in
>   <b>/home/content/08/10141608/html/testing/faceapi/HTTP/Request2/Adapter/Socket.php</b>
>   on line <b>332</b></td></tr> <tr><td
>   colspan="3" style="background-color: #aaaaaa;
>   text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Exception
>   trace</td></tr> <tr><td style="text-align:
>   center; background: #cccccc; width:20px; font-weight:
>   bold;">#</td><td style="text-align: center;
>   background: #cccccc; font-weight:
>   bold;">Function</td><td style="text-align:
>   center; background: #cccccc; font-weight: bold; in
>   **/home/content/08/10141608/html/testing/faceapi/HTTP/Request2/SocketWrapper.php**
>   on line **134**

Let me know if you need any further information...

Thanks...

Comment: anyone out there...?

Comment: YESS...i have resolved it

Comment: PLease how did you solve it, I have been battling it for days now with not positive result